# Play! 2.2.3 Framework SQL Server 2008 script won't run

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, playframework-2.0

I have tried using both microsoft's SQL driver and the sourceforge SQL driver, only the sourceforge driver is working. But it will not run the Database evolution script.

```
db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://LSASCS23:1433/my_site;user=HRUser;password=ReSufdg2;"
db.default.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
db.default.user=HRUser
db.default.password="ReSufdg2"
```

BUILD.SBT -

```
val appDependencies = Seq("net.sourceforge.jtds" % "jtds" % "1.2")
```

When I create my data source it says the connection was successful, following the advice from a comment on a question on this site I pasted applyEvolutions.default=true into my application. conf and came across the

```
unexpected exception: PersistenceException: Query threw 
    SQLException:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'. 
    Bind values:[] Query was: select count(*) from user t0
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this problem. Otherwise it won't run the database apply script, I can also paste my User model if needed.

Answer (score 0):

`User` is a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) so you need to surround it with brackets in order for the query to parse properly.

Try this as your query:  `select count(*) from [user] t0`

Comment: Thank you I tried renaming the User Model to User1 and then I tried renaming it to UserAccounts but I got the same error as above. I'll try it again with your advice.